# "Подождем пока что-то произойдет/не произойдет" - В чем разница?

Tags: выбор-слов, значение-слов

Корректно ли сказать

> Подождем пока что-то произойдет

или корректно только

> Подождем пока что-то не произойдет

Answer (score 2):

Технически, некорректны оба варианта. Оба союза являются подчинительными, поэтому в обоих примерах требуется запятая:

`Подождем, пока что-то произойдет` и `Подождем, пока что-то не произойдет`

Если говорить непосредственно о выборе слова, то первый случай является разговорным вариантом второго.

В первом случае имеется подчинительный союз `пока`, корректное использование которого может быть в значениях:

- `в то время как`, со сказуемым несовершенного вида в придаточной части "Подождем, **пока** что-то *происходит*." (Что-то происходило, и мы решили подождать);
- `прежде чем`, "Ждали, **пока** что-то *произошло*." (Что-то произошло, но пришлось порядком подождать).

Во втором случае имеется подчинительный союз `пока не`, корректное использование которого может быть в значениях:

- придаточное предложение является результатом главного "Подождем, **пока** что-то **не** произойдет" (Что-то произойдет именно потому, что мы ждем);
- придаточное предложение является ограничителем главного "Подождем, **пока** что-то **не** произойдет" (Что-то произойдет, и только тогда мы перестанем ждать).

Если опустить `не` во втором случае, то получится разговорный вариант—сокращенный и упрошенный.

Comment: Ну вариант "пока" в значении "в то время как" в нашей фразе невозможен, ибо сказуемое придаточной части имеет совершенный вид. А вариант "пока" в значении "прежде чем" очень сомнителен. Вот например, пару фраз: "закрой дверь прежде чем станет холодно"  - ok. Но "закрой дверь пока станет холодно"  - ??? это некорректная и непонятная фраза. Так что я склоняюсь к тому что первая фраза не корректна.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ исправлен.

**ПОКА** II. союз. В то время как; до того времени как. П. сын учится, надо ему помочь. П. солнце не взойдёт, на траве лежит иней. Литература существует, п. она понятна. Сердце любит до тех пор, п. не истратит своих сил

**Для глагола "подождем" возможны оба варианта**, так как время  можно обозначить двумя способами: пока событие произойдет, пока не произойдет (это **один и тот же "пограничный"  момент**).

**Пример:** Кажется, на улице дождь. Пойдем гулять? – Подождем, пока  дождь кончится/пока не кончится.  Также: Подождем, пока трава высохнет/не высохнет.

Глагол ***ждать*** тематически **связан со временем**, поэтому для него возможен парный вариант с союзом "пока".  Для других глаголов используется союз "до тех пор как", например:

Будешь повторять до тех пор, пока выучишь/пока не выучишь.

Comment: Почему в разделе союза "пока", присутствуют примеры с другим союзом "пока ... не ..." ?

Comment: Вот нашел интересный комментарий https://scicenter.online/russkiy-yazyik-scicenter/predlojeniya-soyuzom-poka-96767.html Значение предшествования, не осложненного одновременностью, оформляется союзом пока не (см. § 2975).

Comment: Српсибо, я обязательно прочитаю чуть позже.

Comment: Почитайте, там много интересного и понятного. Но вообще тема оказалась не простой.

Comment: Да уж, тема непростая, судя по моим упражнениям, так что хочется разобраться.

Comment: *Для глагола "подождем" возможны оба варианта, так как время можно обозначить двумя способами* Sharon, Как бы вы в соответствии с этим тезисом поняли фразу *"[Посидим дома,] подождем,  пока дождь кончился*?

Answer (score 0):

Второй ответ (исправленный) на доработке

Comment: Ладно, спасибо, надо разбраться.

Answer (score 0):

> Корректно ли сказать
> *Подождем пока что-то произойдет*
> или корректно только
> *Подождем пока что-то не произойдет*

Оба варианта вызывают вопросы. Первый - в большей степени.
Второй вариант возможен только в каком-то особом контексте, для первого контекст должен быть совсем уже фантастическим.

**[Посидим дома,] подождем, пока дождь кончился.???**
Это или не по-русски, или не по здравомыслию.

**[Посидим дома,] подождем, пока дождь не кончился.???**
Это терпимо, но режет глаз два глагола совершенного вида. Хотя бы одно действие должно быть продолженным. А поскольку в русском нет других способов выражения имперфекта, то остается только заменить на
**Ждем, пока дождь не кончился.**
или (что несколько хуже)
**Подождем, пока дождь не кончается.**
Как-то так....